How to decide Function chaining priority
I have a problem link
Where I have only 3 requirements:

Create a function that logs a message with whatever passed in arguments
Chain multiple methods on it.
Give priority in execution of method chaining (e.g. here we need to give priority to sleepFirst, irrespective of its order.)

const LazyMan = (name, logFn)=>{
    logFn(`Hi, I'm ${name}.`)
    return []
}
Array.prototype.sleepFirst = function (time) {
    console.log(`Wake up after ${time} seconds.`)
    return this;
}

Array.prototype.eat = function (food){
    console.log(`Eat ${food}`)
    return this;
}

Array.prototype.sleep = function (second){
    console.log(`Wake up after ${second} seconds.`)
    return this;
}


LazyMan('Ashish', console.log).eat('apple').sleep(10).sleepFirst(20)

Current output:
Hi, I'm Ashish.
Eat apple
Wake up after 10 seconds.
Wake up after 20 seconds.

Expected output:
Wake up after 20 seconds.
Hi, I'm Ashish.
Eat apple
Wake up after 10 seconds.


Possibly related: How to sleep a method in javascript method chaining

you'll also need to fix some minor output issues ... don't plural 1 second ... missing . - oh, and don't forget to actually "sleep" those seconds before outputting - and DO NOT pollute the Array prototype - no need for that

use setTimeout ans tasks to slove this problem


// interface Laziness {
//   sleep: (time: number) => Laziness
//   sleepFirst: (time: number) => Laziness
//   eat: (food: string) => Laziness
// }

/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {(log: string) => void} logFn
 * @returns {Laziness}
 */
function LazyMan(name, logFn) {
    // your code here
    const tasks = [];
    const next = () => {
        const task = tasks.shift();
        if (task) task();
    };
    const Laziness = {
        sleep: (time) => {
            tasks.push(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    logFn(`Wake up after ${time} second${time > 1 ? "s" : ""}.`);
                    next();
                }, time * 1000);
            });
            return Laziness;
        },
        sleepFirst: (time) => {
            tasks.unshift(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    logFn(`Wake up after ${time} second${time > 1 ? "s" : ""}.`);
                    next();
                }, time * 1000);
            });
            return Laziness;
        },
        eat: (food) => {
            tasks.push(() => {
                logFn(`Eat ${food}.`);
                next();
            });
            return Laziness;
        },
    };
    tasks.push(function () {
        logFn(`Hi, I'm ${name}.`);
        next();
    });
    setTimeout(next, 0);
    return Laziness;
}

LazyMan("Jack", console.log).eat("banana").sleepFirst(10).eat("apple").sleep(1);




The only possible flaw I can see in this is one that the site doesn't actually test for - I mean, it does LazyMan('Jack', log).eat('banana').eat('apple').sleepFirst(1).eat('egg').sleepFirst(1) where there's two "sleepFirst" - however they have the same sleep time so order doesn't matter - if they had different sleep time, say 1 then 2, your code would sleepFirst 2 then sleepFirst 1 - not saying your wrong, because your code would almost pass ... if it weren't for the missing . and the 1 seconds instead of 1 second :p

your other flaw is you're sleeping the time in microseconds instead of seconds :p

yes, You're right. If there are multiple sleepFirst functions, the last one will have the highest priority because the unshift method is used to ensure it's the first in the queue.

You mentioned above (e.g. here we need to give priority to sleepFirst, irrespective of its order.)
If you want to differentiate the priority of sleepFirst, you might consider marking sleepFirst to distinguish it.
